# Why Do We Need The Cumulant Function?

Tags: probability

I am trying to understand the difference between **Moment Generating Functions** (MFG - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) and **Cumulant Functions** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant).

- As I understand, the **Moment Generating Function** of a random variable $X$ is defined as:

$$M_X(t) = \mathbb{E}\left[e^{tX}\right]$$

- On the other hand, the **Cumulant Function** of a random variable $X$ is defined as:

$$K_X(t) = \ln M_X(t)$$

As such, **it seems like the Cumulant Function is simply the Natural Logarithm of the Moment Generating Function**.

This being said - why do we even go through the trouble of defining the Cumulant Function when we have the Moment Generating Function (e.g. why not take the cosine of the MGF or the square root of the MGF - why is the natural logarithm of the MGF relevant)?  As such, what kinds of problems can we solve using Cumulant Functions that the Moment Generating Function can not be used for? **Why are Cumulant Functions useful - why do we need them?**

Thanks!

**Note:**

- As a concrete example, I know that Moment Generating Functions present advantages in problems when we are interested in estimating the parameters of certain Probability Distributions.
- For example, suppose we observe some data and believe that this data came from a Gamma Distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) :  $f(x;\alpha,\beta) = \frac{1}{\beta^\alpha \Gamma(\alpha)} x^{\alpha-1} e^{-\frac{x}{\beta}}$
- In this problem, we are required to estimate $\alpha$  and $\beta$ .
- However, we can see that the Gamma Distribution itself contains a Gamma Function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) - if we were to use Maximum Likelihood  Estimation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) to estimate $\alpha$  and $\beta$, this would be quite complicated as we would have determine how to approximate the Gamma Function within the Gamma Distribution and then differentiate this approximation and solve the resulting equations.
- On the other hand, using Moment Generating Functions to estimate $\alpha$  and $\beta$ would not require directly differentiating an approximation of the Gamma Function, therefore making the overall estimation process easier.
- This being said, I am looking for a similar **example which highlights types of problems in which Cumulant Functions exhibit some type of advantage compared to alternate methods.**

Comment: You are conflating *cumulants* (mean, variance, skewness and so forth) with the *cumulant generating function* (which is the expression given by $\ln \mathbb E[e^{t X}]$, and which is the exponential generating function of the cumulants).

Comment: One thing which comes to mind is the Saddlepoint approximation method which can be used to approximate pdfs and is useful to approximate sums and averages of random variables.

Comment: The moment generating function is used to bound tail probabilities. $\log E e^{tX}$ therefore comes up often. Suppose $X \in [a,b]$ almost surely. Then $$E e^{\lambda (X-E X) } \leq e^{\lambda^2 (b-a)^2/8}$$ One way to prove this is to consider the function $\psi(\lambda) = \log E e^{\lambda X}$. Now consider $\psi(0),\psi'(0),\psi'(\lambda), \psi''(\lambda)$. Using the fundamental theorem of calculus and some other tools, one concludes.

Comment: Some useful perspectives on cumulants [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144773/what-is-a-cumulant-really).

Comment: thank you everyone for your kind and generous replies!